# Is there a way to get the result by using 'group by'?

Tags: mysql

table a like this:

```
id | state
1  | a 
2  | a 
3  | b 
4  | c 
5  | d
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
state| count(*)
a    | 2
b,c  | 2
d    | 1
```

Is there a way to get the result? use 'group by' or anything else?

Comment: What is the condition to get b,c | 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can, but you need to query it manually or hard coded in you script:

```
select 
  case 
    when state = 'b' or state = 'c' then 'b,c' 
    else state 
  end as `state`, 
  count(*) as `count` 
from  `table`
```

**edit**

or you could use GROUP_CONCAT with a helper column like:

```
id | state | grouping
1  | a     | 1
2  | a     | 1
3  | b     | 2
4  | c     | 2 
5  | d     | 3
```

then

```
select group_concat(state), count(*)
from `table`
group by grouping
```

Comment: thank u! After a try, I think the first one is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(state), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY state;
```

Ref: [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: since you group it by state, the `b` and `c` would still got their own group. the OP should create another column to help the grouping